# Trimming a variable so it only contains the leftmost 126 characters

Tags: php

How could I trim `$commentt` so it only includes the leftmost 126 characters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
substr($commentt, 0, 126);
```

If the string may contain multi-byte characters (UTF-8 etc.), use:

```
mb_substr($commentt, 0, 126, 'UTF-8');
```